# jQuery script not holding over when I change views/templates with Angular's ngRoute

Tags: jquery, html, angularjs, angular2-routing, single-page-application

I am being forced to build a SPA in a peculiar way. The client only has a static file server, so I cannot use AJAX calls.

I am using Angular's ability to build an in-line template, and it is working nicely. However, the JQuery script I have is not working upon returning to the index page. For now, all I am doing is using JQuery to change the CSS of the images. It is not working when you return the index unless you refresh. I am worried this will continue to be an issue as I build the separate templates and need elements on the mto be styled or animated differently.

Here's the code (IMGS are placeholders, VioeoJS is in the boiler plate for future use):

**HTML**

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link href="http://vjs.zencdn.net/6.8.0/video-js.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="http://vjs.zencdn.net/ie8/1.1.2/videojs-ie8.min.js"></script>
    <link rel ="stylesheet" href ="CSS/custom.css" type = "text/css">
    <title>Know Your Risk</title>
  </head>



  <body ng-app="WXRisk">

    <div ng-view></div>



    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular-route.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular-animate.js"></script>
    <script src = "JS/custom2.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src = "JS/custom.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="http://vjs.zencdn.net/6.8.0/video.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

**AngularJS**

```
 var app = angular.module("WXRisk" , ["ngRoute", "ngAnimate"]);
    app.config(function($routeProvider){
      $routeProvider
      .when ("/", {
        template : "<div class = 'container'><div class ='row'><div class = 'col-xl-6'><a href = '#!Chatham'><img src='http://www.dishuser.com/TVMarkets/City%20Maps/Savannah.gif' class='img-fluid wx' alt=''></a></div><div class = 'col-xl-6'><img src='http://www.dishuser.com/TVMarkets/City%20Maps/Savannah.gif' class='img-fluid wx' alt=''></div></div><div class = 'row'><div class = 'col-xl-6'><img src='http://www.dishuser.com/TVMarkets/City%20Maps/Savannah.gif' class='img-fluid wx' alt=''></div><div class = 'col-xl-6'><img src='http://www.dishuser.com/TVMarkets/City%20Maps/Savannah.gif' class='img-fluid wx' alt=''></div></div></div>"
      })

      .otherwise({
        template : "<div class = 'container'><div class ='row'><div class = 'col-xl-6'><a href = '#!Chatham'><img src='http://www.dishuser.com/TVMarkets/City%20Maps/Savannah.gif' class='img-fluid wx' alt=''></a></div><div class = 'col-xl-6'><img src='http://www.dishuser.com/TVMarkets/City%20Maps/Savannah.gif' class='img-fluid wx' alt=''></div></div><div class = 'row'><div class = 'col-xl-6'><img src='http://www.dishuser.com/TVMarkets/City%20Maps/Savannah.gif' class='img-fluid wx' alt=''></div><div class = 'col-xl-6'><img src='http://www.dishuser.com/TVMarkets/City%20Maps/Savannah.gif' class='img-fluid wx' alt=''></div></div></div>"
      })

      .when("/Chatham", {
        template : "<a href = '#/!'>CLICK</a>"
      });

    });
```

**JQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".wx").hover(function(){
    $(this).css("border", "10px solid red");
    $(this).css("width", "600px");
  }, function(){
    $(this).css("border", "6px solid red");
    $(this).css("width", "500px");
  }
);


  });
```

**CSS**

```
img {
  border: 6px solid red;
  border-radius: 20px;
  width: 500px;
  height: auto;
}

.row {
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  padding-top: 10px;
}

body {
  background-color: black;
}


@keyframes slideOutLeft {
    to      { transform: translateX(-100%); }
}

@keyframes scaleUp {
    from    { opacity: 0.3; -webkit-transform: scale(0.8); }
}


.ng-enter           { animation: scaleUp 0.5s both ease-in; z-index: 8888; }
.ng-leave           { animation: slideOutLeft 0.5s both ease-in; z-index: 9999; }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jQuery `.on` (`.hover` is a shorthand for `.on("mouseenter mouseleave",...)`) only works on elements that are currently in the DOM when you call it. Therefore, since all of your templates are not loaded into the DOM at the same time (that's how angularjs routing works), you must make your jQuery call every time you load a template that has the items you want to bind the hover actions to.

BUT NONE OF THIS IS NEEDED. You can accomplish hover styles with pure CSS:

```
.wx {
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: red;
    border-width: 6px;
    width: 500px;       
}

.wx:hover {
    border-width: 10px;
    width: 600px
}
```

Comment: Can I ask you how I would have the jQuery call itself each time the template loads? I just want to know for the future if I run into scripts that cannot be offloaded into the CSS or elsewhere.

Comment: Haha, honestly I don't know. And my programmer-sense tells me it would be a waste of time. Typically, you don't mix jQuery and AngularJS because it just doesn't make a lot of sense to do so.

Comment: well that explains why it was so confounding trying to solve! Do you think the VideoJS script is going to be messed up as well? I haven’t got to that part of the development process. I suppose if it is messed up, I can build the player elsewhere and iframe it in. Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: VideoJS is a pure Javascript library and should not interfere much with AngularJS. Although I do recommend either building your own AngularJS directive to wrap it, or find a third-party AngularJS wrapper around it.